# Can a Tornado WebSocketHandler receive messages asynchronously?

Tags: javascript, python, tornado, coroutine

On the python side, I've created a `WebSocketHandler`.

```
from tornado import gen
from tornado.escape import json_decode
from tornado.websocket import WebSocketHandler

class Echo(WebSocketHandler):
    ...
    @gen.coroutine
    def on_message(self, message):
        message = json_decode(message)
        response = yield self.do_echo(message)
        self.write_message(response)

    @gen.coroutine
    def do_echo(self, message):
        # emulate long, blocking call
        sleep(randint(0, 5))
        raise gen.Return(message)
```

On the javascript side, I start multiple clients (different browsers) at the same time with:

```
var ws = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:5000/echo');

ws.onmessage = function (evt) {
    console.log(JSON.parse(evt.data));
}

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    var msg = {
        messageid: i,
        payload: 'An echo message.'
    };
    ws.send(JSON.stringify(msg));
}
```

All clients, as expected, finish at roughly the same time. However, each client's received messages are logged in the exact order (`messageid`) that they were sent as if the `WebSocketHandler` is queuing messages. Python logs on the server side reflect this as well.

So then, my questions are:

- Why is each message read and returned in the order that it was sent?
- Is it possible to circumvent this queuing behavior? How?
- Am I completely missing something embarrassingly basic?

Note that this is not the real code but a reasonable facsimile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must never run "long, blocking calls" on the IOLoop thread, because that blocks everything else. That `sleep` call (or whatever it's standing in for), must either be rewritten to be asynchronous or handed off to another thread (which is fairly easy with `concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor`). See http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/faq.html#why-isn-t-this-example-with-time-sleep-running-in-parallel for more on this.

Comment: I clearly misunderstood what I read in the docs. Thanks for the clarification.